# selecting datetime from sqlite3 as localtime with php

Tags: php, datetime, sqlite

I'm trying to select a timestamp from SQlite3 with a PHP script.
but i get different results when selecting from within SQlite3 and from PHP.
in both cases the query is:

```
select datetime(aanmaakdatum,'localtime') as aanmaakdatum from waterverbruik where aanmaakdatum BETWEEN '2015-10-13' and '2015-10-14';
```

the result in php:

```
2015-10-13 07:38:22
2015-10-13 07:38:31
2015-10-13 09:12:21
2015-10-13 09:46:43
```

the result from SQlite3:

```
2015-10-13 09:38:22
2015-10-13 09:38:31
2015-10-13 11:12:21
2015-10-13 11:46:43
```

as you can see PHP isn't corecting for localtime. even dough i have set the server time to local time, i have added `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL.utf8');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');` to the top of my php script.